# responsive div in between two fixed div elements in IE8

Tags: html, css

Im trying to set an responsive div between two fixed width elements. I have a hard time to make this work on IE8 though, which I have to have it work for. Im having a hard time making this work without the use of `calc`

How do i do this?

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GmoLgR

Comment: You could potentially do absolute positioning within the parent of all children where the center one that fills the space is a border-box div with padding left and right of the other elements. Other than that I really don't know how to do it without javascript. I dont have time to write this as an example so I wont post this as the answer.

Comment: @Flipbed Absolute positioned elements that *must* act as normal elements will cause lot's of issues later on.

Answer (score 0):

Make it as table.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.wrapper div {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.fixed {
  width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="fixed"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="fixed"></div>
</div>
```